# PHP - My form page freezes after submitting form

Tags: php, html, forms

Here's the thing. When I submit the form, it works every time UNLESS my Title field is blank.

My HTML on page:

```
Title: <input type="text" name="title"><br />
Description:<br />
<textarea name="desc"></textarea><br /><br />
Location: <input type="text" name="where"><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

My PHP having to do with the title input, on the other page:

```
if(empty($_POST["title"]) or !ctype_alpha(str_ireplace(" ","",$_POST["title"]))){
    $ge=True;
    $et=True;
    }
```

The above if statement just checks to see if the title entered contains letters and spaces ONLY, and to make sure it isn't blank.

It's only when that one text field is blank, and nothing else.

I'm new to PHP so any help would be awesome.
Thanks for your time!
- Eric

**EDIT**

Sorry, should have been more descriptive. The page acts as if it's trying to submit the form (the spinning loading icon thing is there), but it never makes it to the process page. The form page just becomes unresponsive.

Comment: What "freezes" means? Does the area of a monitor near the form literally cover with frost or what?

Comment: The provided code cannot cause that

Comment: it sounds like your posting page has an infinite (or very long!) loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="POST">
            Title: <input type="text" name="title"><br />
            Description:<br />
            <textarea name="desc"></textarea><br /><br />
            Location: <input type="text" name="where"><br />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html> 

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        if(empty($_POST["title"]) or !ctype_alpha(str_ireplace(" ","",$_POST["title"])))
        {
            $ge=True;
            $et=True;
            echo 'empty title';
            exit();
        }
        echo 'form submitted';
    }
?>
```